# Why does the `sa` command (from the acct package) always show "0" for avio?

Tags: user-management, statistics

For example, I get:

```
0 host:~# sa -m
                                     6908 4946803.89re    1211.65cp         0avio      2558k
clamav                                  2  363298.58re     990.07cp         0avio     71384k
root                                 3856 2974216.18re     161.88cp         0avio      2456k
messagebus                              1  193772.20re      52.31cp         0avio      2274k
systemd-timesync                        1  125505.87re       2.24cp         0avio     23280k
postfix                               130   96729.33re       1.75cp         0avio     11068k
spampd                                  6     223.03re       1.41cp         0avio     33627k
nobody                               1364       1.88re       0.37cp         0avio      1118k
```

These processes are definitely reading and writing to disk so I expect a non-zero value for disk i/o related statistics.

Is there a kernel flag or compile flag or command option to get a value for "avio" (also "tio" is not even listed)?

Thank you!

Comment: I am not a c-programmer, but the `0` is probably originating from the source, see line #955 here: https://github.com/Whissi/gnu-acct/blob/master/sa.c

Comment: I just updated my question to clarify that I expect these processes to be consuming disk i/o so I expect a non-zero number. Is there something on line #955 that suggests a configuration change I need to make to get these values to be populated? Or are you suggesting: if it says 0 it means there is no disk i/o for the process?